# Retrieve date saved as string

Tags: mysql, date

I have dates in a database saved as varchar (11 September 2011). I am trying to make a query like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(datum,'%e %M %Y') ='2011')") or die(mysql_error());
```

It's returning `NULL`.

Comment: Frankly, I'd just convert the fields to `date` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(datum,'%d %M %Y'))= 2011;

SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('11 September 2011','%d %M %Y'));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can use this format if your field type is varchar.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE datum LIKE '%2011'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it's not exactly what i was looking for but it do a job, thank you

Comment: @InTry check out my answer ,,this is what actually you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

See this forum post from MySQL Forums and modify the solution to your needs.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,377334,377365

Answer (score 0):

You should change the column type to datetime in table of database  for future purpose. for example, you might need the datetime to do addition, subtraction, count down and so on. thus, this will be easier for you if you want to do comparison or validation. Hence your mysql statement can easy as below.

SELECT something FROM tbl_name WHERE column_name <= date_col;

Answer (score -1):

You will not get the answer because...you have added to database as `varchar()`  then there is no need of `STR_TO_DATE(datum,'%e %M %Y');` just type `select * from table name where column name="2011"`